# How to assert that specific element is located on the LEFT side of page?

Tags: location

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYLb5.png)As part of my Selenium (Java) testing i need to make sure that Webelement is located on the left side of the page. In this situation how would you proceed and what action would you take?

Reference is attached

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the position of the WebElement in `x` and `y` coordinates.
Find a comfortable range for the value of `x`.

You can find a readthrough of this idea on this [link](https://www.scientecheasy.com/2020/07/click-on-webelement.html/)

The Code may look like following -

`WebElement eExportGridButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Export Grid')]"));`

`Actions actions = new Actions(driver);`

`int getX = eExportGridButton.getLocation().getX();`

`System.out.println("X coordinate: " + getX);`